# opencv2.1 settings in visualc++2010

Tags: opencv

i'm using opencv2.1 with visualstudio2010

while debugging it is showing this error message:

'the program can't start because cxcore210.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this program.'

but cxcore210.dll is already present in the /bin folder

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the dll is in your system path or in the same folder as the executable. The best way is to add the OpenCV /bin folder to your PATH environment variable.

http://www.mattmontag.com/development/notes-on-using-opencv-2-3-with-visual-studio-2010

With the runtime errors you are now having that suggest you are using the OpenCV binaries compiled in Visual Studio 2008, the easiest option is to get the OpenCV 2.3.1 Win superpack distribution. It comes with binaries compiled in vs2008 and vs2010. Please see my blog because it also has instructions for configuring this distribution! :)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.3.1/OpenCV-2.3.1-win-superpack.exe/download

Also - the documentation for OpenCV 2.3 at http://opencv.itseez.com/ is generally much cleaner and better than the other versions.

Comment: i did but still got this error message:
'opencv_helloworld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\opencv_helloworld\Debug\opencv_helloworld.exe', Symbols loaded.
'opencv_helloworld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_helloworld.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'opencv_helloworld.exe': Loaded 'C:\OpenCV2.1\bin\cxcore210d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The program '[3880] opencv_helloworld.exe: Native' has exited with code -1072365566 (0xc0150002).

Comment: the PDB messages are not errors.  This error code is because you are building with a different version of Visual Studio (2010) than this version of OpenCV was compiled on (2008). See my answer for edits.

Comment: @MattM. I have the same issue but the OpenCV website says it should be fine that OpenCV is built for 2008. Do you know where I can find the binary for VS 2010?

Comment: the "superpack" includes binaries compiled in both 2008 and 2010.